# Can I edit the look and feel of the moneybookers payment page

Tags: payment-gateway

Can I edit the look and feel (background color or theme, button color, etc) of the moneybookers payment page which is shown to the buyers?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the appearance of these sites.